# A function like pandas.index.get_indexer that can accept two possible lists of values, but not both

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

Sometimes I will need

```
read = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',', skiprows=2)
column_real, column_im = read.columns.get_indexer(['re:Trc3_S24', 'im:Trc3_S24'])
```

and other times I would need

```
read = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',', skiprows=2)
column_real, column_im = read.columns.get_indexer(['re:Trc3_S42', 'im:Trc3_S42'])
```

but never both. Only one list or the other will exist in a given data file. Is there a function that would allow me to get one or the other?

I have tried messing with the tolerance parameter but that seems to only work if both of the lists of column names exist in the data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
read = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',', skiprows=2)
column_index = read.columns.get_indexer(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
column_index = column_index[column_index > 0]
column_real, column_im = column_index
```